# What is the role of D2 and D3 in this circuit?

Tags: diodes, circuit-design, rectifier, thyristor

**Explanation of the circuit :**

This is a simple battery charger based on SCR is shown here. Here the SCR rectifies the AC mains voltage to charge the battery. When the battery connected to the charger gets discharged the battery voltage gets dropped. This inhibits the forward biasing voltage from reaching the base of the transistor Q1 through R4 and D2.This switches off the transistor. When the transistor is turned OFF, the gate of SCR (H1) gets the triggering voltage via R1 & D3.This makes the SCR to conduct and it starts to rectify the AC input voltage. The rectified voltage is given to the battery through the resistor R6(5W).This starts charging of the  battery.

When the battery is completely charged the base of Q1 gets the forward bias signal through the voltage divider circuit made of R3, R4, R5 and D2.This turns the transistor ON. When the Q1 is turned ON the trigger voltage at the gate of SCR is cut off and the SCR is turned OFF. In this condition a very small amount of charge reaches the battery via R2 and D4 for trickle charging.

**The question is**

What is the role of the diodes D2 and D3?

[image]

Comment: This looks like a horrendous battery charger, not anything I'd subject any battery I cared about to!

Comment: Why don't you simulate it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

D3 keeps negative voltage from the SCR gate. Same for D2 and the base of Q2.

On a side note, the design looks to send ~20V pulses to the battery, which when done properly can reduce oxidation effects in the plates of the battery.

Answer (score 0):

Also - D2 increases the voltage required to turn on transistor Q1.  This improves the adjustability and noise immunity of the circuit.

I'm surprised at the low values for R3, R4, R5.

Consider adding a resistor from the Q1 base to its emitter.  This will assure that the transistor really is off when it is supposed to be by preventing the base from floating.  10 K should achieve this without upsetting the circuit function.

For a similar reason, consider adding a 10 K resistor from the H1 gate to its cathode.